# Detect when a different html range slider is in use and display image without reloading image on each step or focus

Tags: javascript, events, rangeslider

Lets say I have 2 basic range sliders like so -

```
<input type="range" id="one">

<input type="range" id="two">
```

And I want to display image #1 when the first slider is in use, and image #2 when slider two is in use.

I have this default image displayed when the page is loaded, I will switch the image when a slider is used in javascript.

```
<img src="image.jpg" class="image" style="display:none;"/>
```

The JS -

```
var sliderOne = document.getElementById("one");
sliderOne.oninput = function() {
    $('.image').fadeOut(200);
    $('.image').replaceWith('<img src="one.jpg" class="image" style="display:none;"/>');
    $('.image').fadeIn(200);
}

var sliderTwo = document.getElementById("two");
sliderTwo.oninput = function() {
    $('.image').fadeOut(200);
    $('.image').replaceWith('<img src="two.jpg" class="image" style="display:none;"/>');
    $('.image').fadeIn(200);
}
```

At this point all is well and the image one fades out and image two fades in. But heres the problem if you couldn't see it already. The image reloads with every step of the slider or if a user focuses out and back into the same slider. I only want the image to load once a new slider is used. How can I detect when a different slider is in use so I can make sure to only load the picture on initial switch between sliders?

- Note: I wrote this example for this post, not my actual script Looking for the logic to accomplish this not necessarily just the code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, using addEventListener with focus solved the issue.

```
sliderOne.addEventListener('focus', function() {});
```